# How to store data for a to-do list app?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and I'm currently working on a todo list app. I would like to store the name of the task and if it is completed or not. Later I might add things like priority or a date when the task has to be finished. I'm just unsure which method of storage i should use. Would SQL, JSON, XML or maybe something else like a CVS file be best fitted for the task?

You don't have to show me how to implement that method, I am just curious which method would be best suited.

Tanks for all answers

Comment: see this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me, if you want some addition scalability from your app in future - it's better to use database. Preferences are not for storing large amount of data, but maybe they take less time for implementation. Don't store in xml/json if you are going to increase stored fields count, it would be a mess after some time.
 If it's some kind of self educational project maybe you would like to use firebase or maybe realm, but it's only if you want to get something new. SQLite would be enough too.

Comment: Tank you for all the answers. It looks like this is really a matter of opinion. I think I might go for SQL and try XML and JSON later for educational purposes.

Answer (score -2):

This is more of a pref. Question. But, XML is pretty much the standard.

Comment: I'd say JSON is more standard than XML these days.  But ignoring that-  without a lot more data on what he needs, we can't say what's best.  If anything its likely to be a database, which shouldn't be storing xml.